# Extract email address from pcap file

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract email addresses for a pcap file that are present in the To and From fields. So far I've been able to get the http/s addresses like so:

```
url = []

for ts, buf in packets:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data

    try:
        if tcp.dport == 80 and len(tcp.data) > 0:
            http = dpkt.http.Request(tcp.data)
            url.append(http.headers.get("referer"))
    except Exception as error:
        None
```

How ever I am trying to extract email addresses from them using this code here:

```
try:
    webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    page_content = webpage.read()
    for email in page_content:
        emails = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", email)
        print(emails, page_content)
except Exception as error:
    None
```

However, I'm not getting any results. I also cannot find any recourses explaining how to distinguish To and From fields.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Full code:

```
def emails(packets):
"""task 3"""
url = []
url_img = []

for ts, buf in packets:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data

    try:
        if tcp.dport == 80 and len(tcp.data) > 0:
            http = dpkt.http.Request(tcp.data)
            url.append(http.headers.get("referer"))
            url_img.append(http.headers.get("accept"))
    except Exception as error:
        None        

try:
    webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    page_content = webpage.read()
    for email in page_content:
        emails = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", email)
        print(emails, page_content)
except Exception as error:
    None
```

Comment: Do you mean email address or IP address? Your code certainly looks like the later.

Comment: I mean email address? what part of this looks like it refers to IP?

Comment: The regular expressions that look for 4 numbers separated by dots. Also, you check port 80 (http), not pop, imap, or smtp ports.

Comment: Ah yea thats the wrong regex. Your right. Thanks. However, even with the right regex its still not working